# Simple DateTime program is not displaying date?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new in Asp.NET

I'm trying to show date using this program:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="inde.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.inde" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Page_Load()
    {
        lblServerTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:yyyy");
    }

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    The current date and time is:

    <asp:Label
        id="lblServerTime"
        Runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it display nothing except this:

Output:

```
The current date and time is:
```

Please help!!

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to put your Page_Load method to the code behind file inde.aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblServerTime" runat="server" ><%= System.DateTime.Now %></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

CodeBehind="inde.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.inde"

And it will work.